# echo specific elements from an xml response

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have an xml response for a DHL tracking and i want to echo specific elements on my php page.

I use the following code to print out the tracking results without formatting:

```
print_r($response);
```

The xml response looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [TrackingResponse] => Array
        (
            [xmlns:req] => http://www.dhl.com
            [xmlns:xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
            [xsi:schemaLocation] => http://www.dhl.com TrackingResponse.xsd
            [Response] => Array
                (
                    [ServiceHeader] => Array
                        (
                            [MessageTime] => 2013-12-12T11:51:05+00:00
                            [MessageReference] => j2xfhcBpCE2yd9gbeC5tjqxIX8xjDpZ1
                            [SiteID] => iraqnova
                        )

                )

            [AWBInfo] => Array
                (
                    [AWBNumber] => 8564385550
                    [Status] => Array
                        (
                            [ActionStatus] => success
                        )

                    [ShipmentInfo] => Array
                        (
                            [OriginServiceArea] => Array
                                (
                                    [ServiceAreaCode] => FRA
                                    [Description] => FRANKFURT - GERMANY
                                )

                            [DestinationServiceArea] => Array
                                (
                                    [ServiceAreaCode] => MLA
                                    [Description] => MALTA - MALTA
                                )

                            [ShipperName] => STANDARD CHARTERED BANK
                            [ShipperAccountNumber] => 144193851
                            [ConsigneeName] => BANK OF VALLETTA P.L.C
                            [ShipmentDate] => 2013-02-14T15:14:00
                            [Pieces] => 1
                            [Weight] => 0.08
                            [WeightUnit] => K
                            [GlobalProductCode] => U
                            [ShipmentDesc] => 1402130018
                            [DlvyNotificationFlag] => Y
                            [Shipper] => Array
                                (
                                    [City] => Frankfurt/Main
                                    [PostalCode] => 60486
                                    [CountryCode] => DE
                                )

                            [Consignee] => Array
                                (
                                    [City] => Santa Venera
                                    [PostalCode] => 9030
                                    [CountryCode] => MT
                                )

                            [ShipperReference] => Array
                                (
                                    [ReferenceID] => Doc
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm getting lost with so many foreach loops to get to the specific xml tags inside the  [ShipmentInfo] tag:

```
foreach($response as $tag){
echo $tag['ShipmentInfo'];
}
```

The sample tracking number and info, from the DHL XML Service Validation website http://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/serviceval/jsps/main/Main_menu.jsp

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$arr['TrackingResponse']['AWBInfo']['ShipmentInfo']` will lead to the shipment info and then iterate over this using `foreach`.

Like -

```
if(is_array($arr['TrackingResponse']['AWBInfo']['ShipmentInfo'])) {
foreach(is_array($arr['TrackingResponse']['AWBInfo']['ShipmentInfo']) as $shiptagkey=>$shiptagval)
{
echo $shiptagkey, " ", $shiptagval;
}
}
```

Although `$shiptagval` itself going to be an array so you need to care about this as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($response ['TrackingResponse']['AWBInfo']['ShipmentInfo']);
```

or if you don't know the path: (pseudocode)

```
function findAndEcho($obj,$tag) {
  for $obj as $key => $val {
    if $key = $tag {
      print_r($val)
    }
    else if is_array($val) {
      findAndEcho($val,$tag)
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely going to throw an error, most expectedly `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '('` Also remember `=` != `==` && != `===`

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was great just like the other one. I had to choose one as a best answer. but both are great and solved my problem. Thank you again.